# Is there any property in CSS which is equivalent to "max-height" and "max-width" to scale images proportionally?

Tags: android, html, css

It is annoying that some of the CSS Properties are not working on some Android phones. Same is the case with `max-height` and `max-width` properties.

Is there any equivalent CSS properties to handle such things? 
In case of Images, the images should be scalable according to the proportion.
Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5f2ZY/3/) for the same.

Comment: The equivalent for max-height/max-width for images is... max-height/max-width!  There *is* a property that forces elements to preserve their aspect ratio, but only Opera implements it:  http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-object-fit-object-position/

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if is any equivalent propierty but you can do it this way:

you obtain the width and the heigth on the mainActivity.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Then set a default value for your image width and heigth.

Then calculate your new value.